# Windows 10 (November Update) File Explorer crashes

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

File Explorer crashes when doing full environment scan. The stack trace shows only Microsoft libraries (see below). The last thing I did was attaching my Android phone and copying pictures to this computer.

```
>   msvcrt.dll!memcpy()    Unknown
SHCore.dll!`anonymous namespace'::_TryActionOnPageBackedDataWithExceptionHandling<class <lambda_d757ca68eb788d9a9e57e73b107a4322> >(class <lambda_d757ca68eb788d9a9e57e73b107a4322> const &)    Unknown
SHCore.dll!CSharedStream::Read(void *,unsigned long,unsigned long *)    Unknown
mfplat.dll!CMFByteStreamOnStream::OnRead(struct IMFAsyncResult *)   Unknown
mfplat.dll!CMFByteStreamOnStream::OnReadAsyncCallback::Invoke(struct IMFAsyncResult *)  Unknown
RTWorkQ.dll!BaseRecycler::~BaseRecycler(void)   Unknown
ntdll.dll!TppWorkpExecuteCallback()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread() Unknown
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

Comment: What's a "full environment scan"?

Comment: File Explorer opens successfully if you open a specific folder.

Comment: If you start the application generically it scans all attached devices and local network devices. It goes down while doing the scan.

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you unplug your Android phone?  Any related errors in the Event Logs?

Comment: Yes. I assume a driver was installed via Plug and Play which causes a problem.

Comment: The Event Log shows the same issue:Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d4c0
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d79e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000073b20
Faulting process id: 0x1044
Faulting application start time: 0x01d13c2bdb965534
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: 53af40a7-c2dc-4786-a468-0bc44185a8cc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: After some more tries I was able to sidestep the issue by switching File Explorer to go to This PC view by default as opposed to Quick access. I would still appreciate somebody finding the reason for this crash.

Comment: diasble the thumbnails in explorer options. if this doesn't help, share the dmp (compressed as zip on Onedrive), maybe I can see more.

Comment: I use detailed view. Explorer is fine going thru each individual folder under Quick Access. It crashes when I click on Quick Access group and it has to scan the entire group.

Comment: Here is the URL to today's dump magicandre1981: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7C24BB4D6DEA344A%21144). Thanks for your help!

Comment: ok, downloading 4GB will take some time. I only have 16MBit DL speed. I'll post an answer when I got the dump.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I looked at the dump and the [chkimg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function shows some errors. The downloaded files from the symbol server don't match to the DLLs that are part of the dump in small parts.

```
0:119> !chkimg -lo 50 -d !ntdll -v
Searching for module with expression: !ntdll
Will apply relocation fixups to file used for comparison
Will ignore NOP/LOCK errors
Will ignore patched instructions
Image specific ignores will be applied
Comparison image path: D:\sym\dl\nt\ntdll.dll\56540C3B1c1000\ntdll.dll
No range specified

Scanning section:    .text
Size: 1024297
Range to scan: 7fff32851000-7fff3294b129
Total bytes compared: 1024297(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:     PAGE
Size: 224
Range to scan: 7fff3294c000-7fff3294c0e0
Total bytes compared: 224(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:       RT
Size: 485
Range to scan: 7fff3294d000-7fff3294d1e5
Total bytes compared: 485(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:   .rdata
Size: 264200
Range to scan: 7fff3294e000-7fff3298e808
    7fff3294e001-7fff3294e002  2 bytes - ntdll!_guard_dispatch_icall_fptr+1
    [ 85 8f:51 8e ]
Total bytes compared: 264200(100%)
Number of errors: 2

Scanning section:   .pdata
Size: 51168
Range to scan: 7fff32998000-7fff329a47e0
Total bytes compared: 51168(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:    .rsrc
Size: 418328
Range to scan: 7fff329a9000-7fff32a0f218
Total bytes compared: 418328(100%)
Number of errors: 0
2 errors : !ntdll (7fff3294e001-7fff3294e002)
0:119> !chkimg -lo 50 -d !kernel32 -v
Searching for module with expression: !kernel32
Will apply relocation fixups to file used for comparison
Will ignore NOP/LOCK errors
Will ignore patched instructions
Image specific ignores will be applied
Comparison image path: D:\sym\dl\ke\kernel32.dll\5632D5AAad000\kernel32.dll
No range specified

Scanning section:    .text
Size: 473881
Range to scan: 7fff31b11000-7fff31b84b19
Total bytes compared: 473881(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:   .rdata
Size: 189366
Range to scan: 7fff31b85000-7fff31bb33b6
    7fff31b87770-7fff31b87773  4 bytes - kernel32!_guard_check_icall_fptr
    [ a0 d0 b3 31:00 51 8e 32 ]
    7fff31b87778-7fff31b8777b  4 bytes - kernel32!_guard_dispatch_icall_fptr (+0x08)
    [ e0 e7 b3 31:50 51 8e 32 ]
Total bytes compared: 189366(100%)
Number of errors: 8

Scanning section:   .pdata
Size: 22236
Range to scan: 7fff31bb5000-7fff31bba6dc
Total bytes compared: 22236(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:    .rsrc
Size: 1320
Range to scan: 7fff31bbb000-7fff31bbb528
Total bytes compared: 1320(100%)
Number of errors: 0
8 errors : !kernel32 (7fff31b87770-7fff31b8777b)
0:119> !chkimg -lo 50 -d !user32 -v
Searching for module with expression: !user32
Will apply relocation fixups to file used for comparison
Will ignore NOP/LOCK errors
Will ignore patched instructions
Image specific ignores will be applied
Comparison image path: D:\sym\dl\us\user32.dll\565423D2156000\user32.dll
No range specified

Scanning section:    .text
Size: 584738
Range to scan: 7fff30451000-7fff304dfc22
Total bytes compared: 584738(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:   .rdata
Size: 99980
Range to scan: 7fff304e0000-7fff304f868c
    7fff304e0d30-7fff304e0d33  4 bytes - user32!_guard_check_icall_fptr
    [ 70 14 48 30:00 51 8e 32 ]
    7fff304e0d38-7fff304e0d3b  4 bytes - user32!_guard_dispatch_icall_fptr (+0x08)
    [ 30 ac 48 30:50 51 8e 32 ]
Total bytes compared: 99980(100%)
Number of errors: 8

Scanning section:   .pdata
Size: 38928
Range to scan: 7fff304fb000-7fff30504810
Total bytes compared: 38928(100%)
Number of errors: 0

Scanning section:    .rsrc
Size: 648128
Range to scan: 7fff30506000-7fff305a43c0
Total bytes compared: 648128(100%)
Number of errors: 0
8 errors : !user32 (7fff304e0d30-7fff304e0d3b)
```

Test your RAM first for errors (memtest86+) maybe the RAM is damaged and flips some bits. Next check your HDD (`chkdsk /f`), maybe this corrupts the DLLs when reading them and if both show no issues, run `sfc /scannow` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` to detect if the files are already damaged in the HDD for what ever reason.

Comment: magicandre1981: Thanks a lot for your efforts! I ran the tests (although replaced memtest86+ with one provided by Dell, the manufacturer) - no errors detected. I also ran the repair tools - everything was perfect. After finishing I selected 'Quick Access' and it crashed again. At the same time I recalled that my video goes down periodically ever since I installed second monitor using integrated graphics for it as I have only one video card. I probably need to talk to Dell support. Thanks again!

Comment: have you tried the sfc and DISM commands to detect and repair corrupted files?

Comment: Yes, I did. The first one didn't find any problems, while the second one gave the message 'successful' upon completion. Unfortunatety as I mentioned before it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I'll ask Microsoft after the Christmas holidays for help. Remind me next week.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely remind you. I want to get to the root of the issue which is not really possible when dealing with OEMs. Right before it started happening I connected my Android phone for the first time and the system installed some drivers. Just for fun I tried experimenting with a different user account on the same computer - File Explorer works fine there.

Comment: ok, this sounds like a bad shell extension that is installed on your main account but not in the new account

Comment: Magicandre1981: if it is true it would be interesting to find out which bad shell extension is activated when File Explorer creates/refreshes a Quick Access group. I use my main account for software development for more than 3 years. Over that time I installed a number of utilities with shell extensions such as Tortoise. However I never experienced these crashes until, as I suspect, Plug and Play installed Android support activated during Quick Access enumeration.

Comment: Do you recommend using  [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html), which comes first from Google?

Comment: yes, the tool from Nirsoft is great to look for shellextensions and disable them

Answer (score 0):

By excluding all possibilities one after another I came to realization that File Explorer crashes while creating Recent Files list. As File Explorer takes some time during the crash before disappearing from view I used this time to look carefully at the files it managed to list and found thumbnails there. I found directions how to disable all thumbnails in a [forum](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/18834-thumbnail-previews-file-explorer-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html#option1). After disabling all thumbnails I was able to select Quick Access option without File Explorer going down.

The apparent reason for the crash is difficulty in acquiring all thumbnails for Recent Files.

Sorry, magicandre1981, for not acting properly on your initial recommendation to disable all thumbnails.